# Restart OS X if an application has crashed/is not responding/beachballed?

Tags: macos, applescript, crash, launchd, restart

How can I automatically restart the machine if an application has crashed in any way? It might have cleanly exited, have a quit unexpectedly error, or be frozen with the spinning beachball.

I don't want to relaunch the app, but do a full restart.

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to define crashed , if exited then it is not running, if frozen then how do you know it is frozen? Also why reboot the whole OS why not just the process?

Comment: Any application, or a specific application?

Comment: A specific application that I am developing. Crashed as in it throws an exception and exits or has another type of error. Frozen as in High CPU usage / Not responding after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of of research, trial and error, I have come to the conclusion there is no reliable way to do this. Therefore have used an approach that will only work with certain applications, in this case one that modifies a file every nSeconds. Obviously if the application has crashed, exited, or frozen this will not happen.

My Apple Script monitors this file, and if it detects that it hasn't been modifies after nSeconds it will force a restart of the machine.

```
-- Watchdog Script --
--
-- Continually checks that a file is modified, otherwise will force a system restart
-- 2013 David Penney

-- Config
set HFSpath to "app/data/logfile.log"
set username to "user"
set passwrd to "pass"
set updateIntervalSeconds to 5
-- End Config

set lastModTime to "Deltron 3030"
delay (60)

repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        set newModTime to modification date of file HFSpath
    end tell
    if newModTime is equal to lastModTime then
        do shell script "shutdown -r now" user name username password passwrd with administrator privileges
        log "booooooM"
    else
        set lastModTime to newModTime
        log "coolio"
    end if
    delay (updateIntervalSeconds)
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Shalalalala with the name of the process you want to monitor.

```
property NameOfVictim : "Shalalalala"


tell application "System Events"
    set ps to get the name of every process

    repeat while ps contains NameOfVictim
        set ps to get the name of every process
    end repeat

    restart
end tell
```

Comment: Great for a 'clean' crash / exit, but this doesn't seem to work for a frozen/SBBOD app. In Activity monitor I can see the process with the name "Shalalalala" (Not Responding) with CPU > 99% It should also restart in this situation

Comment: Could you then specify when you call an application crashed?

Comment: When it throws an exception of some description.

Comment: Throwing an exception does not lead to high CPU usage.

Comment: Yeah just makes the application exit. But when I put a Freeze (High CPU) test in, I also want to be able to recover from that.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. But when do you consider an application hung? After what time in what state?

Comment: Oh sorry, in this case after a second or two, when the GUI becomes unresponsive, or the spinning beach ball appears.